# How to list directories which are contains only two letters?

Tags: linux, command, ls

I want to make a command where I list that directories which are contains only two letters.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

`?` is a wildcard for one character. So, the following should work:

```
ls -d ??/
```

The `-d` prevents `ls` from listing the contents of the directories, the final `/` excludes files.

Comment: Works perfect on linux specifying `-d` before or after the directory name, for MacOS is required to specify the `-d` flag before the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -F | grep -o "^.\{2\}/$"
```

`ls -F` lists content by file system object type
`| grep -o` filters out anything that doesn't match the regex expression `^.\{2\}/$` which basically says 'match only folders with 2 **characters** in their name'

Answer (score 0):

```
ls */ | awk 'length($0) < 3'
```

Note that this does not match hidden directories. **choroba**'s answer is better, because it is usually a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`, but I like this for its readability.